# Relations between the homotopy class and the orientation of the connected sum of two manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, orientation

> I want to find some general arguments about why it can happen that $$ M \sharp \overline{M} \not\simeq M \sharp M$$ for $M$ a compact orientable odd dimensional manifold, which is **chiral**, i.e. ($M \not\simeq \overline{M}$). By $\overline{M}$ I mean the same manifold equipped with the reversed orientation.

[In this M.O. answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93434/when-is-the-connected-sum-of-manifolds-orientation-independent) They are considering $CP^2\sharp \overline{CP}^2$ and use the intersection form, but this is a specific tool for $4k$-dim manifolds, and hence I cannot use it in this case.

In this [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5283.pdf) at page $3$ they consider the so called Linking Form for odd dimensional closed manifolds, but I'm not able to find a clear definition of it anywhere, and more importantly, what are its properties.

[Here Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/connected-sum/) claims that if $M$ is chiral, then $M \sharp M  \not\simeq M \sharp \overline{M}$. I'm mostly interested in this case, but I cannot understand the reasoning he does.

> Is there some more easy arguments to prove the claim in the case that $M$ is chiral and odd dimensional?

**My first attempt** was to prove that in the case that $M \sharp M \simeq M \sharp \overline{M}$ I could somewhat obtain  a map from $M$ to $\overline{M}$, but I doubt that this approach will work (not easy and not true in general that I can find maps from $M$ to the connected sum). I searched for some suitable invariants but didn't found anything

Comment: The reasoning in the blog post you linked is strictly for $3$-manifolds and can be proven from prime decomposition quite easily (As $M$ and $\overline{M}$ have non-equal prime decompositions, $M \# \overline{M}$ and $M \# M$ have non-equal prime decompositions). I think there are probably counterexamples in general, but I do not know one off hand.